# Reduce height of sqrt

Tags: spacing, height, sqrt

There are many questions here about increasing the height of the square root (e.g. [How to adjust/increase the height of square root?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455584/how-to-adjust-increase-the-height-of-square-root)), but I'd like to decrease it. Consider the following code and picture:

```
\sqrt{\tfrac{2 \log \left(2 n T^{2}\right)}{s}}
```

[image]

I think the exponent on the T is causing issues, so maybe lowering the exponent may help? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't use `\left(`...`\right)`. Instead, just use `(`...`)`.

Comment: @Werner that helps a little bit, but perhaps there is a more fine-grained control that LaTeX provides over the height of the square root?

Comment: I see nothing particularly strange when `\left` and `\right` are omitted.

Comment: You can use \smash to ignore the extra height from the 2. E.g. \smash{2nT^2} will get rid of the tiny difference in the height of the bars after removing \left and \right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I present five possibilities. The top one is your, where `\left` and `\right` are the cause for the big space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{with \texttt{\string\left...\string\right}}&\quad&
\sqrt{\tfrac{2 \log \left(2 n T^{2}\right)}{s}}
\\
&\text{without \texttt{\string\left...\string\right}}&&
\sqrt{\tfrac{2 \log (2 n T^{2})}{s}}
\\
&\text{with \texttt{\string\cramped}}&&
\sqrt{\tfrac{\cramped{2 \log (2 n T^{2})}}{s}}
\\
&\text{smashing the numerator}&&
\sqrt{\tfrac{2\smash[t]{{}\log (2 n T^{2})}}{s}}
\\
&\text{smashing and cramping the numerator}&&
\sqrt{\tfrac{2\smash[t]{{}\log (2 n \cramped{T^{2}})}}{s}}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd go with the simplest one, that is, (2).

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is actually the pair of parentheses under the square root. Does the following code do what you want?

```
\sqrt{\tfrac{2 \log \smash[t]{\left( 2 n T^{2} \right)}\vphantom{T^2}}{s}}
```

[image]

*Edit*: as suggested by Mico, you can also use this code:

```
\sqrt{\tfrac{2\log\left(\smash[t]{2 n T^{2}}\right)}{s}}
```

[image]

However, the parentheses are a bit too small for my taste.

Comment: +1. You might also show the output produced by `\left(\smash[t]{ 2 n T^{2}} \right)`.

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I'll add it in a moment.